# Join two tables A and B if no record exist in B

Tags: sql, sql-server

still new on SQL but trying - please bare with me.

My goal is, to get a list of all users incl. the count of rides. If not done any ride yet, this user will not be collected in the Rides table, so there's no matching UserId in this table.

**Table A: Rides**

| UserId | RideId |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 |
| 54321 | 2 |
| 12345 | 3 |

**Table B: Users**

| UserId |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 54321 |
| 67890 |

Thanks in advance!

From my understanding a left join should create the table I want but indeed it's not...

```
select      A.UserId,
        count (B.RideId) as CountRides
from Users A WITH(NOLOCK)
left join Rides B on (A.UserId = B.RideID)
group by A.idUser
```

Table I want:

| UserId | CountRides |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2 |
| 54321 | 1 |
| 67890 | NULL |

Comment: Your current query looks correct.  What is the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the results you're currently getting for the sample data shown.

Comment: Aside... if you're new to SQL Server then you probably shouldn't be using `WITH (NOLOCK)` hints. It allows you to make dirty reads so your query can include results that haven't actually been committed yet (and may get rolled back at a later point in time). It's not a magical "go faster" hint, there are no unicorns and faeries here.

Comment: If you get error messages (and you do) publish them..

Answer (score 2):

You're joining UserId to RideID and then grouping by idUser.

Try this instead

```
select  A.UserId,
        count (B.RideId) as CountRides
from Users A WITH(NOLOCK)
left join Rides B on (A.UserId = B.UserId)
group by A.UserId
```

Comment: Also `COUNT(*)` would yield `0` instead of `NULL` for user 67890.

Answer (score 0):

the alias used in the SELECT clause (A.UserId) is inconsistent with the alias used in the GROUP BY clause (A.idUser). It may be a typo, and the two should match for the query to function as intended